# How to call a function when Modal has loaded?

Tags: jquery

I have the function below. I want to call the function when the myModal has finished loading. This is what I have so far.

```
(function ($) {


    $.ajaxSetup({"error":function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus, errorThrown) {
          alert(textStatus);
          alert(errorThrown);
          alert(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
      }});

    function get_fun() {

         $.getJSON('/sms/fetch/', function(json) {
            alert('json: ' + json + ' ...');
        });


    };


})(jQuery, window, document);
```

on page: **How do I now call my function?**

```
<script src="/js/smart.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myModal').on('shown', function() {


      get_fun()
    })
});
</script>
```

**I get the error: ReferenceError: get_fun is not defined**

Comment: After the Modal has loaded here the alert is I want to now call the get_fun function.

Comment: updated the question to make it clear, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't call `get_fun` since it is a private closure method inside another anonymous function. One possible solution is to assign it to a global object and expose it as given below

Try

```
var utils = {};
(function ($) {
    $.ajaxSetup({"error":function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(textStatus);
        alert(errorThrown);
        alert(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
    }});

    utils.get_fun =    function get_fun() {

        $.getJSON('/sms/fetch/', function(json) {
            alert('json: ' + json + ' ...');
        });       
    };
})(jQuery, window, document);
```

Then call it using

```
utils.get_fun()
```

Answer (score 11):

Found this on W3 school and works for me. Try it out. https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_js_modal_event_shown&stacked=h

```
    $("#myModal").on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
        alert('The modal is fully shown.');
   });
```

Comment: Thanks. This approach worked well for the Bootstrap 4 modal that I am using.

Answer (score 5):

use load event to perform the task.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myModal').on('load', function() {

       alert("hello!")
    })
});
</script>
```

Comment: alryt, and you have got answer too :)